# Python converting string to latex using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, parsing, latex, substitution

Say I have a string

```
string = "{1/100}"
```

I want to use regular expressions in Python to convert it into

```
new_string = "\frac{1}{100}"
```

I think I would need to use something like this

```
new_string = re.sub(r'{.+/.+}', r'', string)
```

But I'm stuck on what I would put in order to preserve the characters in the fraction, in this example 1 and 100.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `()` to capture the numbers. Then use `\1` and `\2` to refer to them:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'{(.+)/(.+)}', r'\\frac{\1}{\2}', string)
# \frac{1}{100}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to escape the backslash `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

Capture the numbers using parens and then reference them in the replacement text using `\1` and `\2`.  For example:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'{(.+)/(.+)}', r'\\frac{\1}{\2}', "{1/100}")
\frac{1}{100}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside the braces would be a number`/`number. So in the regex place numbers(`[0-9]`) instead of a `.`(dot).

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "{1/100}"
>>> new = re.sub(r'{([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)}', r'\\frac{\1}{\2}', string)
>>> print new
\frac{1}{100}
```

Comment: There's no reason to restrict the arguments to numbers. `\frac` doesn't care what the two arguments are; it just typesets them, one above and one below the [vincumulm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)).

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.match`. It's more flexible:

```
>>> m = re.match(r'{(.+)/(.+)}', string)
>>> m.groups()
('1', '100')
>>> new_string = "\\frac{%s}{%s}"%m.groups()
>>> print new_string
\frac{1}{100}
```